Will CSR format store the all 0 column?
In the matrix(3 rows and 7 columns) below with 4 all zero columns

0 4 0 0 0 0 0
2 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 3 0 0 0 0

The CSR format of storage is :

row_ptr: [0, 1, 3, 4]
col_ind: [0, 0, 1, 2]
values: [4, 2, 1, 3]

And if we use this CSR format to recover the matrix,we will get:

0 4 0
2 1 0
0 0 3

The all zero columns in the right side of matrix is missing!
I'm so confused. Though the zero is not important for information storage,the size of matrix is changed.
Hope you can help me!
Thanks!

Most sparse matrix representations are not shape-preserving for all inputs. You have to store the shape of the matrix separately.
